# mod_rewrite - do two redirects - if the first one dosen't match do the second

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my htaccess file at the moment

```
RewriteEngine On

# Only redirect if file dosen't exist.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)     /admin.php          
RewriteRule ^([^/])         /index.php          [L]
```

I don't have any idea why this doesn't work. I think I've finally grasped mod_rewrite and then it just does something completely unexpected like this.

Basically if the URL is domain.com/admin/something then I want it to redirect to domain.com/admin.php (including if its just /admin). However if its ANYTHING else I want it to redirect to index.php.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

# No redirect, if file or directory exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)     /admin.php          [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$         /index.php         [L]
```

Didnt test it. The interesting part is the `L`-Flag after the admin-rule, because it prevents the next rule from matching.

I changed the `RewriteCond`-Statements, because they only apply to the one next `RewriteRule` and (in your case) doesnt affect the rule to `index.php`.

Comment: This will work, just need to remove the leading `/` on the second RewriteRule.

Comment: i've edited the answer to clmarquart's comment incase anyone else comes across this question in the future